# CSS can't change text color in a div class

Tags: html, css

I have made a button using a div. I am trying to make the text white, however the styling is behaving strangely.

Here is the CSS portion:

```
.button a
{
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.button  :hover
{
    background-color: #000000;  
}
```

The page can be viewed here: http://www.clccomputing.net/comf413/01/menu.html

As you can see, the text on the button is not white.

Strangely, if I add the types `a:link`, `a:visited` to the CSS, the header layout collapses and the style applies to the TripAdvisor widget in the right sidebar, like so:

[Image link](http://i58.tinypic.com/2udwefd.jpg)

HTML up to the button:

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <header>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Red 16 Cafe logo"/></a>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li><li><a href="specials.html">Specials</a></li><li><a href="map.html">Map</a></li><li><a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>


    <article>
        <div id="articletext">
            <a name="top"><h1>Our Menu</h1></a>
            <br>
            <div class="button">
                <a href="Red16MenuFeb2014.pdf">Download .PDF for printing</a>
            </div>
```

Comment: What's the relevant HTML?

Comment: Looks like it's being overriden by this: `#articletext a, a:link, a:visited {
color: #000000;
}`

Comment: Look at the style hierarchy in you browsers developer tools; `#articletext a, a:link, a:visited` overrides `.button a`

Comment: Just to clarify are you talking about the download PDF button?

Comment: Checkout [this](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) resource. I think it will answer some of your questions and help you understand why the CSS is behaving like it is. It's due to the precedence of selectors and how they are ranked against one another. If you know and understand the precedence rules, it makes overwriting styles really simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css code below is overruling the `color:#FFFFFF;`

In file `style.css` **line 138**

```
#articletext a, a:link, a:visited {
    color: #000000;                    /* Css line 138
}
```

You could **delete** that code and use this (for the `<h1>` to be **black**).

```
#articletext h1 {
        color: #000000;               
}
```